# BSOD and first screen is freeze after reboot

Tags: windows-xp, bios, bsod

Today my friend told me that he can't start his PC, he also told that after several minutes of work BSOD is appear. After that I try to start his pc and like my friend said "he worked for several minutes, show BSOD and start to reboot".

But after, when i try to start it again i saw first screen with text `"Press DEL to enter setup"` etc. And i watch this to this screen during near 5 minutes, And nothing more! If i push to keyboard buttons it looks like that PC is react and change phrase to `"BIOS is setup"` but BIOS screen is not appear after that.

My First idea was that PC is overheat and second idea was that BIOS battery is empty.
I don't ask about deep analyse what can happen but if you give me some ideas what can happen with friends PC, I'll say you big thanks.

Comment: So far you've actually tried anything to repair this?  What was the stop error on the Blue Screen you were seeing? Have you tried stripping it down of all hardware until it will boot (like leaving only the MB, CPU, RAM and PSU)?  Have you tested the hard drive (in another machine)?  If you pull the RAM does it beep like it has no RAM?

Comment: This really is unanswerable in the current form. We will need more information to answer this question properly. (hint: the BSOD `STOP` error code often tells you exactly what the problem is)

Comment: i can't get BSOD stop error code cause i can't boot windows and repeat this case, after this error start screen is frezze and only if i push delete button, BIOS also don't started too. It's really hard understand what i need to do at start cause i don;t have any beep sound which sais me that RAM memory fail or any other things. 2techie007 thanks for editing, I'm not tested this cases yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure the RAM is sitted well.
- Make sure the internal hard drive and CDROM cables are connected well.
- Make sure the hard drive has  OS installed.
- Finally, make sure that Master Boot Record (MBR) and/or GRUB is not corrupted.

It would be of more help if you can gather additional information before posting. But then you are helping a friend so it is understandable.